# Sharing an object for binding (specifically an NSDocument) between various views / nibs

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdocument, nswindowcontroller, nsviewcontroller

I'm writing an application for OSX (Lion) using Xcode 4.

Hitting a bit of a wall with this one and the internet has thus-far proved not particularly helpful.

I have a document defined, as well as the MainMenu.xib and a document window; The document window is of course what gets created when a document is loaded / created, and therefore has access to the relevant data.

I want to utilise Cocoa Bindings as much as possible in this project, so my question is this:

If I create another View (let's say an NSViewController with a linked Nib); how do I allow it access to the data for the document?

I've tried adding an #import for the document class, but that causes issues when I add the #import on the document class to the view controller (to create it) - I get unknown type compile errors.

I've also gone down the route of passing interim objects around (and even accessing getters / setters after creating the view controller); surely there must be a better, cleaner way?

The application has just the one NSWindowController (the default) and that is it, it's vanilla from the XCode non-core data document-based application template.

Thanks for your help,
Clint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a reference to the document of some kind in your other classes if you want to bind to it. Since you're already using an `NSViewController` you can set the `representedObject` of the `NSViewController` to your document. Alternatively, you could subclass `NSViewController` and create a custom property to refer to the document.

```
YourViewController* controller = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourNib" bundle:nil];
[controller setRepresentedObject:yourDocument];
```

In Interface Builder you can then bind objects in your view controller nib to **File's Owner** using a key path of `representedObject.<some property of your document>`.

Comment: I will test this later when I'm near my prized mac :p (I write windows software for the money). Thanks so much for the help!